# No operator "=" matches these operands C++

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to create a basic text game and I keep getting an error when I try to assign a value to the variable `coinFlip`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string coinFlipValue;
    mt19937 randomGenerator(time(0));
    uniform_int_distribution <int> diceRoll(1, 6);
    uniform_int_distribution <int> coinFlip(1, 2);

    coinFlip = coinFlip(randomGenerator);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

So I am just trying to assign a random coinFlip value that is either 1 or 2.

Comment: *"So I am just trying to assign a random coinFlip value that is either 1 or 2."* - to what? The distribution?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message? And which line causes it?

Comment: Is this really the complete code? Shouldn't there be a `coinFlip` function somewhere?

Comment: [coinFlip(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator%28%29) will return `int`, so you *can't* assign it to `coinFlip`.

Answer (score 2):

```
coinFlip = coinFlip(randomGenerator);
```

You are trying to assign the result of calling `coinFlip()` to the variable `coinFlip`. Notice that you are using the same name as both a variable and as a function. I doubt this is what you want. You should probably use different names here.

Comment: `coinFlip` is not a function.

Comment: @LogicStuff Okay, it's probably a functor. What is the correct general term for something that allows the user of the `()` operator? A "callable"?

Comment: @LogicStuff Also, note that my statement is "you are using [coinFlip]... **as a** function". I'm not saying that it **is a** function.

Comment: *:A "callable"?" * I guess so. `coinFlip = coinFlip(randomGenerator);` could be a valid code for an object if you wanted to. Here, you not only need different names, but also different type for that variable, and that is `int`.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped. :)

Comment: @ThomasAllred Please accept the answer which helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `coinFlip(randomGenerator);` is `int`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()

You need to use:

```
int coinFlipValue = coinFlip(randomGenerator);
```

or a more idiomatic form:

```
auto coinFlipValue = coinFlip(randomGenerator);
```

and remove the line

```
string coinFlipValue;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now! :D